Receive data from radio input group per POST with thymeleaf
Here’s your translated text:

Basically, I have this form:
Picture of the form
<form method="post" th:action="@{/solution-add}">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="'questionId'" th:value="${questionId}">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="'questionType'" th:value="${questionType}">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>True</th>
                <th>False</th>
                <th>Statement</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody th:each="statement, iter : ${statementsList}">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" th:name="${'solution[' + iter.index + ']'}" th:value="${true}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" th:name="${'solution[' + iter.index + ']'}" th:value="${false}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><span th:text="${statement.getStatement()}"></span></label>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a class="btn btn-primary prev-btn" th:href="@{/student-test/{testId}/index/{index}(testId=${testId}, index=${index+-1})}">← back</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary save-btn" type="submit">Save solution</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <a th:if="${isLastQuestion}" class="btn btn-success next-btn" href="/submit-student-test">Submit</a>
            <a th:unless="${isLastQuestion}" class="btn btn-primary next-btn" th:href="@{/student-test/{testId}/index/{index}(testId=${testId}, index=${index+1})}">Next question →</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

So, I have no idea how I should receive the data in the backend controller. I have created a class:
public class SolutionForm {
    private String questionId;
    private String questionType;
    private String solution;
}

And the controller has SolutionForm as an attribute. But how do I receive what is dynamically rendered in:
th:name="${'solution[' + iter.index + ']'}"


What I exatcly want is, that if the user chooses for example true and true, that I can get a string "true,true" and then I process it next.
